# Fit 118 buttons - Android

Tags: android, button

I am developing a periodic table app for android. But I am having trouble fitting all the 118 buttons that denote the elements in my layout.

This is what i have written so far :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".GridActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="H"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
    android:background="@drawable/table_button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="Li"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
    android:background="@drawable/table_button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
    android:background="@drawable/table_button"
    android:text="Na"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2" />

<!--And the rest 115 buttons so on ...-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it looks like on a Nexus 4.

[image]

But, This layout is giving problems on small screen devices (last 3 colmns are getting out of the screen, etc.) And on large screen tablets, this layout is too small. Please help me accomodate this large number of buttons and please give a sample code of your ideas! Please please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider that unless you're on a tablet-sized device, your average person's fingers are going to be mashing on anywhere from 4 to 9 "buttons", then ask yourself if that's a useful interface.

Comment: @MarcB I  thought about it, but then thats how a periodic table looks like right? If you have any ideas for a new interface, plese tell me.

Comment: do like (say) Chrome does on android - for "too close together to tell" clickable areas, pop up a zoomed-in view where the individual clickable areas are far larger than an average finger pad can take up.

Comment: Yes, I will be implementing the zoom feature. But, basically I want to fit all the element buttons in a nice way on the user's screen. And then, the user can zoom in - out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use a LinearLayout as parent, linearlayouts for each row, using weight to be sure all buttons are the same width and height, and placing "empty" buttons on the empty spaces. That way no matter the screen size, the layout will fit itself with weight

EDIT:

Here is a simple example. You have 8 rows and 18 cols, so the parent linear layout has a weightsum of 8, so each row you add will have a weight of 1 and they'll all be equally high.

Inside, you have 8 vertical linearlayouts, each with a weightsum of 18, and in each, you have the element buttons with weight 1.

This way, all buttons are the same height and weight, you can keep the table structure, and it'll adapt itself to any screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="8" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="18" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_button"
        android:text="H" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <!-- 16 of these -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_button"
        android:text="He" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="18" >

    <!-- ... -->

</LinearLayout>

<!-- ... -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice idea. I am just a beginner and 14 years old. Can you please post a sample code for me to better understand it?

Comment: I have editted my post with an example, i think it's exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But the code is having some problems because i am not able to see anything. Please correct it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: apologies, i forgot to set android:orientation="vertical" in the parent layout. fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are a genius! It helped me a lot. Just one last thing.. How do I make the button text size flexible like the buttons?

Comment: for that, i'd recommend you use dimensions. It won't be 100% flexible, but it should be flexible enough to make you app work in any device.